# How to classify adult websites

Tags: php

Is there any dictionary out there containing adult words (black/grey) to identify websites? Would need to exclude some user transmitted sites.

Comment: mind to explain what are the black/grey adult words?

Comment: black words are definitly adult words where the grey words may be adult related (if you want to score the site, black words have much more weight than grey ones)

Comment: should not that known as black-list, white-list, grey-list? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: yes if you add these words to lists, its correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) can filter porn/spam, scams and malware.

b) If you want to filter the porn images then you should check this out -> [pornsweeper](http://www.dansdata.com/pornsweeper.htm)

c) you might also consider implementing "Report this link" moderation.